# Bigquery : Star schema or Denormalized

Tags: database-design, google-bigquery

We are moving our existing datawarehouse from Netezza to BigQuery. In Netezza the data model that we have is star schema. Even though BigQuery supports star schema it suggests that we denormalize the table in order to avoid incurring more cost.

We have some large dimensions (in terms of rows and columns) which are refreshed on a daily basis ([Slowly changing dimension Type 1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slowly_changing_dimension)).

**Is it better that we denormalize or keep these dimensions as-is ?**

If we are denormalizing, we need to make sure these dimensions are updated on all the fact tables on a daily basis for all the historical records.

And moreover some of these dimensions are [conformed dimensions](https://www.jamesserra.com/archive/2011/11/conformed-dimensions/#:%7E:text=A%20conformed%20dimension%20is%20a,consistent%20reporting%20across%20the%20enterprise.).

What would be the better approach here ?

Answer (score 4):

For any large migration in general, try not to chase two rabbits at a time.

If you keep one thing fixed it will make your migration much less of a headache. If I have to name 3 most important things about migration, they are going to be: Parity, Parity, and Parity.

In your very case:

1. First, ***Keep your schema fixed* and migrate data and logic.**

   Unless you're the one of the luckiest people in the world, you will
   face enough problem migrating to a DWH with different SQL dialect.
   Make your query/view/ETL/reporting logic on par with legacy system
   first.
2. Then, once you have everything running on BigQuery well, **try to denormalize based on your performance benchmark**.

   This really depends on how frequent or how much you will update your fact table. *For instance, it doesn't make sense if you do a daily refresh of the past 2 years of data.*  There are lots of middle ground which you have to explore with your own data and requirements.